# Python code that extracts a file in a folder based on new modification/creation date

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I have a folder that contains multiple files of same name, only the difference is the creation date. I want my python script to pick the file which has the latest creation date and even the time i.e. hh:mm:ss if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The below code would fetch you the latest file based on creation date timestamp.

```py
import os
files = os.listdir()
sorted([(os.stat(x).st_ctime,x) for x in files],reverse=True)[0][1]
```

Comment: here if I want to give path to that folder it will be `files = "path/to/the/folder"` and **x** in your code is the name of the file?

Comment: Yes ```x``` is the name of the file, and if you want to give the path you give it inside ```os.listdir(path)``` and the above should work for you

Comment: It gives me this error, "NameError: name 'abcxyz' is not defined". If I include the extension like 'abcxyz.pth' then it gives me this error, "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'somefile.pth'", which is the second file in the folder and has a different name.